# Microsoft Graph API v1.0 self service reset password missing

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

I would like to follow Microsoft instructions and use Microsoft Graph v1.0 instead of Azure Graph Api. Unfortunately i don't see possibility to allow user for password reset.

Additionally i would like to discover possibilities for Self service password reset using graph API. My purpose is to create custom page for resetting password for user. Application authentication will be build using ROPC approach.

Comment: Do you have a chance to look into my answer? Anything else is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Update user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to update user's `passwordProfile` property to reset user's password.

An example:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
{
     "passwordProfile":
    {
      "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn":false,
      "password": "**"
    }
}
```

For Self service password reset, just take advantage of [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) and use Delegated Permission to allow users to reset their own passwords.

Comment: Using Azure ADB2C how can you grant your application the permissions to Update the passwordProfile.  The above code fails with insufficient permissions.

Comment: @StevenT.Cramer See the **Note** tip: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions: `When updating the passwordProfile property, the following permission is required: Directory.AccessAsUser.All.`